# Autocomplete jQuery com API local

Tags: html, jquery, api

Criei uma input text e através do jQuery estou fazendo um autocomplete, consegui fazer funcionar colocando dados locais, como faço para mostrar os dados de uma API gerada como localhost. Não estou sabendo fazer como trocar isso.

Segue meu código:

```
<!-- Importado os arquivos do Jquery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Criando um input que receberá o autocomplete -->
<input type="text" id="fruta" placeholder="Informe uma fruta"/>

<!-- Meu código Jquery em um arquivo que chamei de fruta.js -->
<script>
   $(function() {
       var frutas = ["Ameixa", "Amora", "Banana", "Uva", "Maça"];
       $("#fruta" ).autocomplete({
           source: frutas
   });
});
</script>
```

Como disse, ele funciona pegando as informações localmente. Estou procurando e não encontro nada parecido com minha situação.

Agora eu preciso trocar para que ele pegue informações dessa API criada: `http://localhost:5000/frutas`

Como posso fazer essa troca ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma requisição [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) para a sua API. O que vai acontecer é o seguinte: O ajax vai enviar uma requisição pra sua API assincronamente e após algum tempo vai obter a resposta da sua API, enquanto que o resto do seu código vai continuar executando.

Se a resposta da sua API for texto, minha recomendação é que você estruture a resposta da sua API usando algum formato conhecido como JSON, XML, e etc....

Quando você obter a resposta, basta inserir seu código de autocompletar com os dados que sua API deu.

Comment: Bom dia Samuel. Obrigado pela reposta. Vou pesquisar como fazer isso. Sou novo em jQuery e não tenho a mínima ideia como fazer. rsrsrsrs

Comment: clica nesse link que coloquei na resposta que ele abre um site com várias informações sobre

Comment: obrigado Samuel. Consegui fazer.

Comment: Poste aqui como vc conseguiu fazer, vai ajudar outras pessoas